# Twitter API - how to create new tweets

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

I would like to post new tweets on my twitter account via API.

How is it possible via Zend Framework Zend_Service_Twitter class?

Or through clean php?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
  $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(

      'username' => 'johndoe',

      'accessToken' => $token

  ));

  $response   = $twitter->status->update('My Great Tweet');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Comment: That's crazy... Nice job getting it fixed